# Use of Scalar component in Rotation-Vector-Sensor?

Tags: android, android-sensors

What is the use of the Scalar component of the Rotation-Vector-Sensor in Android?

The documentation states it's optional and the samples don't use it. Does optional mean it's not supported by every device that supports the sensor?

I'm used to quaternion style rotation notations where the first 3 values define the vector and the fourth defines the rotation around that vector. But android seems to use a different approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html) says:

```
SensorEvent.values[0] Rotation vector component along the x axis (x * sin(θ/2)). Unitless 
SensorEvent.values[1] Rotation vector component along the y axis (y * sin(θ/2)). 
SensorEvent.values[2] Rotation vector component along the z axis (z * sin(θ/2)). 
SensorEvent.values[3] Scalar component of the rotation vector ((cos(θ/2)).1
```

this is a unit quaternion (X,Y,Z,W) used by android. Since W=sqrt(X^2+Y^2+Z^2), you can calculate values[3] by yourself with values[0],  values[1](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html), values[2]. My experience is that most android devices do not ouput the values[3] value.

The quaternion used by android (X,Y,Z,W) could be converted to what you were using (x,y,z,θ), just as the doc says

```
X=x * sin(θ/2)
Y=...
Z=...
W=cos(θ/2)
```

so you can get (x,y,z,θ):

```
x=X/sin(θ/2)
y=...
z=...
θ=arcsin(sqrt(X^2+Y^2+Z^2))*2
```